# Change From One State Machine To Another

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a project where I need to state from leds turning on and off to another one that will have all the leds turned on and send data and I was wondering how should I do that, this the code I have:

```
#include <CapacitiveSensor.h>

CapacitiveSensor cs_11_10 = CapacitiveSensor(11,10);

int state_s1 = 0;
int state_s2 = 0;
int state_s3 = 0;
int state_s4 = 0;
int state_prev_s1 =0;
int pin_s1 = 12;
int val_s1 = 0;

const unsigned int ledPins[]={2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
const unsigned int lenledPins=9; 

unsigned long t_s1 = 0;
unsigned long t_0_s1 = 0;
unsigned long t_s3 = 0;
unsigned long t_0_s3 = 0;
unsigned long t_0_s4 = 0;
unsigned long t_s4 = 0;
unsigned long t_s2_4 = 0;
unsigned long tiempo = 250;

unsigned long bounce_delay_s1 = 5;

long total = 0;

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(pin_s1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  for(int i=0; i<(9); i++)
  {
    pinMode(ledPins[i], OUTPUT);  
  }

  cs_11_10.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop()
{


  MBoton();          //MAQUINA DE ESTADO

 MaquinaGeneral();

  if(state_s2 == 1)
  {
    led(); 
  }

  if(state_s1 != state_prev_s1)
  {
    Serial.print("state =");
    Serial.println(state_s3);
  }

  if(state_s4 == 6)
  {
    for(int i=0; i<lenledPins; i++)
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPins[i],HIGH); 
    }
  }

  Serial.print("");

}

void MaquinaGeneral()
{
  switch(state_s2)
  {
    case 0:
    if(state_s1 == 4)
    { 
      state_s2 = 1;
    } 
    break;

    case 1:

    break;
  }
}  


void MBoton()
{
  state_prev_s1 = state_s1;
  switch(state_s1)
  {
    case 0:         //RESET
    state_s1 = 1;
    break;

    case 1:        //START
    val_s1 = digitalRead(pin_s1);
    if(val_s1 == LOW)
     {
      state_s1 = 2;
     }
    break;

    case 2:         // GO!
    t_0_s1 = millis();
    state_s1 = 3;
    break;

    case 3:         //WAIT
    t_s1 = millis();
    if(t_s1 - t_0_s1 >= bounce_delay_s1)
    {
      state_s1 = 5;
    }
    break;

    case 5:         //ARMED
    val_s1 = digitalRead(pin_s1);
    if(val_s1 == HIGH)
     {
      state_s1 = 4;
     }
    break;

    case 4:       //TRIGGERED
    state_s1 = 0;
    break;


  }
}

void led()
{

  switch(state_s3)
  {      
    case 0:         //OFF
    for(int i=0; i<lenledPins; i=i+2)
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPins[i],LOW);
    }
    for(int i=1; i<lenledPins; i=i+2)
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPins[i],HIGH);
    } 

    t_0_s3 = millis();
    state_s3 = 1;
    break;

    case 1:         //WAIT
    t_s3 = millis();
    if(t_s3 - t_0_s3 >= tiempo)
    {
      state_s3 = 2;
    }
    break;

    case 2:         // ON
     for(int i=0; i<lenledPins; i=i+2)
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPins[i],HIGH);
    }

     for(int i=1; i<lenledPins; i=i+2)
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPins[i],LOW);
    }

    t_0_s3 = millis();
    state_s3 = 3;
    break;

    case 3:         //WAIT   
    t_s3 = millis();
    if(t_s3 - t_0_s3 >= tiempo)  
    {
     state_s3 = 0;
    }
    break;


  }


  }

void Capacitor()
 {

  switch(state_s4)
  {

    case 0:         //RESET
    state_s4 = 1;
    break;

    case 1:        //START
    total = cs_11_10.capacitiveSensor(10);
    if(total >= 1000)
     {
      state_s4 = 2;
     }
    break;

    case 2:         // GO!
    t_0_s4 = millis();
    state_s4 = 3;
    break;

    case 3:         //WAIT
    total = cs_11_10.capacitiveSensor(10);
    if(total < 1000)
     {
      state_s4 = 0;
     }

    t_s4 = millis();

    if(t_s4 - t_0_s4 >= 2000)
    {
      state_s4 = 5;
    }

    break;

    case 5:         //ARMED & WAIT
    t_s2_4 = millis();
    total = cs_11_10.capacitiveSensor(10);
    if(total < 1000)
     {
      state_s4 = 4;
     }

     if(t_s2_4-t_s4 >= 1000)
     {  
      state_s4= 6;
     }
    break;

    case 4:       //TRIGGERED
    state_s4 = 0;
    break;


    case 6:     // ARMED 2  
    Serial.println("Entro al estado 6");
    total = cs_11_10.capacitiveSensor(10);
    break;

}
}
```

Comment: A quick scan of your code would suggest you have too much going on.  That  or not enough comments to explain your decision to use multiple state machines.  I would start over with only 1 state machine and stick with only 1 state machine.

Comment: I don't quite understand, what your problem is with doing so. You have written all these state machines. So  you can just add states for exactly what you want (a state that would leave the LEDs on and would send data). Though I think st2000 is right in that you should check thoroughly if using only 1 state machine would be sufficient. That would be way easier to code.

Comment: Also use an enumeration type for the states, instead of 'magic numbers' 1, 2, 3 etc.

Comment: I highly recommend you design state machines with a state-diagram showing events, transitions, and actions. They are a whole lot easier to read & understand than any state-machine code I've ever seen or written. When you have a diagram you believe does what you want, then start coding it. Remember to check your state-machine code against the diagram, to be confident your code does what the diagram says it should. The state-diagram should be your working reference. When you debug, debug/fix it on the diagram first, then use that to fix the code. You'll get a working state machine much sooner.

Answer (score 1):

If you think you need two finite state machines, where only one of them
is running at any given time, then it is trivial to combine them
together: draw them side by side, and add the required transitions
between them. The set of states of the combined FSM will be the union of
the states of the initial FSMs. For example, if you have:

- FSM 1 states: `STATE_A`, `STATE_B`, `STATE_C`
- FSM 2 stages: `STATE_D`, `STATE_E`
- global states: `FSM_1_RUNNING`, `FSM_2_RUNNING`

Then the combined FSM will have the states `STATE_A`, `STATE_B`,
`STATE_C`, `STATE_D` and `STATE_E`, and all the transitions of both
initial FSMs.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what others have commented, this is not the best implementation of a Finite State Machine (FSM). You should establish clear states and define what happens during all transitions of your system.

Follow Edgar's advice on using enumerators for your states.

Nick Gammon's guide will surely be of great help: https://www.gammon.com.au/statemachine